# Laravel Searching by distance from users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, distance

Hey so I have this search form which works perfectly, all except for the distance from the user, I am kind of lost how I would get this working but here is what I have

```
public static function Search($input)
{
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinute(30);
    $query = User::rightJoin('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id');

    if (isset($input ['minAge']) && $input['minAge']) {
        $minAge = $input['minAge'];
        $maxDate = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subYears($minAge)->endOfDay();
    }

    if (isset($input ['maxAge']) && $input['maxAge']) {
        if ($input['maxAge'] < $input['minAge']) {
            $maxAge = $input['minAge'];
        }
        else {
            $maxAge = $input['maxAge'];
        }
        $minDate = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subYears($maxAge + 1);
    }

    if (isset($input['u']) && $input['u'])
        $query->where('users.username', '=', $input['u']);
    if (isset($input['p'])  && $input['p'])
        $query->where('user_profiles.postcode', '=', $input ['p']);
    if (isset($input['o1']) && $input['o1'])
        $query->where('users.last_online','>=',$date);
    if (isset($input['o2']) && $input['o2'])
        $query->whereNotNull('user_profiles.avatar');
    if (isset($input ['o3']) && $input['o3'])
        $query->orderBy('users.type', 'ASC');
    if (isset($input ['minAge']) && $input['minAge'])
        $query->whereBetween('user_profiles.dob', [$minDate, $maxDate]);
    if (isset($input ['g']))
        $query->whereIn('user_profiles.gender',$input ['g']);
    if (isset($input ['d']))
        $query->select('user_profiles.lat, user_profiles.long
            ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                       cos( radians( lat ) )
                       * cos( radians( long ) - radians(?)
                       ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                       sin( radians( lat ) ) )
                     ) AS distance'
            )
        ->having("distance", "<", "?")
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->setBindings([$input['lat'], $input['long'], $input['lat'],  $input['d']]);


    $query->orderBy('users.last_online', 'DESC');
    $users = $query->paginate(10);
    return $users;
}
```

Where it has if (isset($input ['d'])) this is my input for the select of distance from the user which the options are set like so 5 for 5kms and 10 for 10kms and so on.

Once I search the query it says that the column distance does not exist and it does not exist, I thought the whole math about working out the users longitude and latitude set the distance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DB::raw()` to wrap around the code.

It looks like you copied your code from here but removed the raw statement: http://laravel.io/forum/04-23-2014-convert-this-geolocation-query-to-query-builder-for

Comment: So $query->DB::raw()?? Because I am trying this while using the join statement and im not sure if this is at all possible

Comment: So I have it working on its own however, I want to meld this with the whole query and I am not to sure how to work it into the whole query  eg, is it possible to do $query = DB::select( as $query->DB::select(     type of thing